# Taking picture with Camera Intent never get back to onActivityResult()

Tags: android, android-camera, onactivityresult

I have an activity which is called from a `TabActivity` (I know it's deprecated) as:

```
intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this, sin2.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("Second").setContent(intent2);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

which is an activity that takes pictures, save them and set a thumbnail. It works perfectly on a lot of devices but on *Samsung Galaxy Pocket* or *Galaxy Wonder* (always Android 2.x) **sometimes** when I start the Camera Intent, it never gets back to `onActivityResult()`, that means:

1. I take a picture
2. I save it
3. I doesn't get back to `onActivityResult()`
4. It allows me to take another picture

and looping... I never get back, if I press `finish()`, I come back to my current activity.

I've read on StackOverflow about doing stuff like `getParent().startActivityForResult(Intent,RequestCode);` but doesn't work.

This is how I take my pictures:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
mMakePhotoUri = Uri.fromFile(photofile);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMakePhotoUri);
startActivityForResult(i, num);
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == 1)
        {
            .............. things I do.
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

---

MY CODE:

on onCreate (`photo` is a BitMap):

```
        scatta.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            photo = null; 
            if(foto1.getDrawable()==null)
                foto(1);
            else if(foto2.getDrawable()==null)
                foto(2);
            else if(foto3.getDrawable()==null)
                foto(3);
            else
                Toast.makeText(sinistri2.this, "Cancella una foto per poter scattare un'altra", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

foto(int) function:

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public void hacerfoto(int num){
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
String n = sdf.format(new Date());
String fotoname = "Immagine-"+ n +".jpg";
File photostorage = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File photostorage2 = new File(photostorage, "im");
photostorage2.mkdirs();
photofile = new File(photostorage2, fotoname);

Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
mMakePhotoUri = Uri.fromFile(photofile);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMakePhotoUri);
startActivityForResult(i, num);
}
```

my onActivityResult function:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String filename = sacarfoto();

    if (requestCode == 1){

        sacarfoto();


        if(photo != null){
            ruta1 = sacarfoto();
            foto1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
            photo = f.resize(photo, filename);
            foto1.setImageBitmap(photo);

            cancellare1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        else{
            cancellare1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            foto1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fondoicona);
            Toast.makeText(this, "C'è stato un errore, riprova a scattare la foto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(ruta1);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    if (requestCode == 2){
        sacarfoto();
        if(photo != null){
            ruta2 = sacarfoto();
            photo = f.resize(photo, filename);
            foto2.setImageBitmap(photo);
            foto2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
            cancellare2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            cancellare2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            foto2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fondoicona);
            Toast.makeText(this, "C'è stato un errore, riprova a scattare la foto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try{
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(ruta2);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    if (requestCode == 3){
         sacarfoto();

        if(photo != null){
            ruta3 = sacarfoto();
            photo = f.resize(photo, filename);
            foto3.setImageBitmap(photo);
            foto3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
            cancellare3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        else{
            cancellare3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            foto3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fondoicona);
            Toast.makeText(this, "C'è stato un errore, riprova a scattare la foto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(ruta3);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    if (requestCode == 4) {

        try{
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            photo = f.decodeAndResizeFile(new File(selectedImagePath));


        } catch(NullPointerException ex){
            try {
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);        
            }
        }
            if(photo != null){
                if (foto1.getDrawable()==null){
                    photo = f.resize(photo,selectedImagePath);
                    ruta1 = selectedImagePath;
                    foto1.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    foto1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
                    cancellare1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else if (foto2.getDrawable()==null){
                    photo = f.resize(photo,selectedImagePath);
                    ruta2 = selectedImagePath;
                    foto2.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    foto2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
                    cancellare2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else if (foto3.getDrawable()==null){
                    photo = f.resize(photo,selectedImagePath);
                    ruta3 = selectedImagePath;
                    foto3.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    foto3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
                    cancellare3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(sinistri2.this, "Cancella una foto per poter scattare un'altra", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
            else{

                Toast.makeText(this, "Non si è potuto riuscire, riprova scattando una foto o scegliendo una foto dalla gallery.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
    }

}
```

the function `sacarfoto()` gives a String but sometimes works for doing a process, but it doesn't matter in this error.

Comment: What is the value of "num" ?

Comment: I have many `if (requestCode == someNum)` and I handle it... it works fine on some devices, for example mine.

num could be 1, 2 or 3

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you think that it's never returned, but in fact it's returning a `RESULT_CANCEL`. Try to add `if(result == RESULT_CANCEL)` in your `onActivityResult`. Maybe it was impossible for the camera to save the picture or something like that.

Comment: but, it sometimes works fine... I mean... if that time doesn't work, I restart the app and works fine... would you give me this answer anyway? =). Thanks for your time.

Comment: try to do some debugging and figure out what's wrong. Is the intent returning null extras? is the image saved?

Comment: Yes, the image is saved as I said, then the intent is null =)

Comment: mmm that's really weird. Android is so frustrating sometimes. Let me know if you find a workaround

Comment: I have to try that of RESULT_CANCEL... I'm not on my "coder" computer now... will notice soon, thanks again ;)

Comment: tra italiani ci si aiuta ;)